# SSH Login Display

Tags: server, ssh, configuration

So I enabled the banner which displays a nice ascii art text for me. Once I enter my password, some system stats come up, my last login info, and this is where the server tells me if there are updates.

**How do I edit this portion?**

I want to potentially add more stuff to this output.

Comment: Check out this article and see if it helps you do what you need: http://www.howtogeek.com/104708/how-to-customize-ubuntus-message-of-the-day/

Comment: I have followed this type of guide already. I don't seem to have a motd file. Would making one work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add it to either `/etc/bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`.